# For which matrices deciding permutation similarity is polynomial?

Tags: graph-theory, matrices

> Q1 For which matrices deciding permutation similarity is polynomial?

It is not easier than graph isomorphism (and very likely is equivalent to it).

If necessary, assume the entries are nonnegative integers.

Partial answer are the adjacency matrices of graphs in classes, where GI is polynomial.

Comment: Here's a tautological answer: the identity matrix :-) --- more interesting answers will include easy cases of GI, but you already know all that...

Comment: @Suvrit also permutation matrices. I am looking for something broader if doable.